# Twisted not sending anything until connection is closed

Tags: python, networking, twisted

The problem is, that Twisted doesn't seem to ever send anything until you close the connection. The problem is visible both on my client and firefox(the server isn't sending).

Here's the full code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint,TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor
import thread
class echoProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        self.transport.write(data+"\n - Server")

class echoFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        print addr.host
        return echoProtocol()

class clientProtocol(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self,message):
        self.transport.write(message)
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print data

class clientFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        return clientProtocol()

def messageLoop(p):
    while 1 :
        text=raw_input("")
        p.sendMessage(text)

def connectedProtocol(p):
    thread.start_new_thread(messageLoop, p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice=raw_input("Server?[y/n]")
    if choice.lower()=="y":
        TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor,44554).listen(echoFactory())
        reactor.run()
    else:
        TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor,"127.0.0.1",44554).connect(clientFactory()).addCallback(connectedProtocol)
        reactor.run()
```

How do I make Twisted actually send something before closing the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punching in `ctrl-c` in your looping callback shows the problem. Your protocol is stuck in "write" mode and can never get to the `dataReceived` section until after it leaves the callback.

Is there any reason you can't follow the default [echo client example](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto2)? You also don't have `reactor.stop` called anywhere.

The primary problem is a misunderstanding of the deferred concept. You block inside the while loop, which means you never get to the `dataReceived`. But if you don't loop, how do you continue sending data? You need to add another deferred *within your current deferred*.

Notice in the [code for the single use client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html) how the callback `gotProtocol` adds another message to the reactor for calling later, then adds a closing callback. You need to make a recursive callback setup.

Here's your code, set up to recursively chain an additional callback as needed. It also has a shutdown function for the errback chain. You should add some code to check the contents of `raw_input` and attach a closing callback if something like `quit` is input. Otherwise it loops forever, unless the user hits it with `ctrl-c`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint,TCP4ClientEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor
import thread

class echoProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        self.transport.write(data+"\n - Server")

class echoFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        print addr.host
        return echoProtocol()

class clientProtocol(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self,message):
        self.transport.write(message)
    def dataReceived(self,data):
        print data

class clientFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        return clientProtocol()

def messageLoop(p):
    text=raw_input("")
    p.sendMessage(text)
    reactor.callLater(1, messageLoop, p)

def connectedProtocol(p):
    thread.start_new_thread(messageLoop, p)

def shutdown(ignored):
    reactor.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    choice=raw_input("Server?[y/n]")
    if choice.lower()=="y":
        TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor,44554).listen(echoFactory())
        reactor.run()
    else:
        TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor,"127.0.0.1",44554).connect(clientFactory()).addCallback(messageLoop).addErrback(shutdown)
        reactor.run()
```

Comment: Oops! Again I forgot to edit the file to it's current form. I call the connectedProtocol to start messageLoop in another thread, so it won't block. Anyways, a thread was not the answer. Thank you!

Comment: But there aren't any Deferreds anywhere in this program.  When you say "the deferred concept", I think perhaps you mean "event driven programming".  Deferreds are more specific than that.  Also, this version of the code calls p.sendMessage and reactor.callLater in a non-reactor thread.  This is unsupported and will have unpredictable (usually bad) results.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Argle! You may be able to tell I picked up twisted in less than a week, and my grasp of the concepts are just a bit fuzzy. You're right, it's event driven, not deferred. The twisted docs just seem to mix deferred in with callbacks everywhere. I forgot that the protocol starts new threads, so feel free to edit the entry with a more proper example. I know it solves the problem though, at least for the limited test of "getting the desired results when I turned it on".

Comment: Protocol doesn't start a new thread.  thread.start_new_thread starts a new thread. :P

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are reading lines but not sending lines. In this circumstance the read blocks until it gets a newline or EOS. If you never send an EOL you will get one big line when you close the socket.

Comment: Nope, didn't help. I tried to attach "\n" and "\0" to the message, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

What is `connectedProtocol`?  Nothing in your sample uses it, but it sits there evoking images of nasty thread-related bugs in your actual application.

Apart from that, `writeSomeData` is the wrong method to call.  Try `write` instead.

Comment: Oops, i left the writeSomeData there by accident. It was meant to be write. That didn't fix the problem, though. As for connectedProtocol, thanks for pointing it out. Actually it's a bug that i forgot to call it! And after all that, it's still not working.